# Hibernate XML ArrayList

Tags: xml, hibernate, arraylist

I have this relation in my application:

```
Entry 1:n Guest
```

The `Entry.class` contains the following property:

```
Entry {
  ...
  List<Guest> guestList = new ArrayList<Guest>();
  ...
}
```

I would like to configure this `guestList` property for lazy loading in Hibernate, but it doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
<class name="...." table="entry">
  <id name="id" column="entry_id" type='long'>
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>

  ...other properties...

  <list name="guestList" table="guest" cascade="all">
    <key column="entry_fk"/>
    <index column="guest_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Guest"/>
  </list>

  ...other properties...

</class>
```

Here is a description of the Guest table schema:

```
table : guest[guest_id,entry_fk,guestName,...]
```

By the way...

- I can't use annotations in this project.
- Preferably, I'd like to use lazy loading (as soon as it works)
- I have no index in my table, but Hibernate keeps asking for this definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with XML mapping, but I see at least two errors:

1. Your field should be declared as `List<Guest>`, to allow Hibernate injecting its own lazy-loaded list implementation (always use interfaces rather than concreate types is a best practice anyway, but it's mandatory with Hibernate)
2. If it's a list, it needs an index. Else, it's a bag. The index is supposed to hold the index of the guest in the list. The ID is tus not the index.

Otherwise, one-to-many mappings are described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-12m). Replace the `set` in the example by a `bag`, and it should be OK.

Comment: thanks for your advice!
regarding 1. I'm sorry, in my deployed code i have List<Guest> instead of ArrayList<Guest> - I did a mistake in the example. (updated it now.)

Does anyone have concrete suggestions for 2.?

Comment: My answer contains a suggestion. Add an index column, or use `bag` instead of `list`.